# Get text between two elements JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in my application.

```
 <div title="Please Click Here to Expand" class="technology3 closedlanguage" headerindex="0h">
<span class="accordprefix">
<img src="http:www.test.com/expanded.gif" style="width:13px; height:13px; margin-Right:20px"> 
</span> 
  Need this text<span class="accordsuffix"></span></div>
```

I need to get text between "accordprefix" and "accordsuffix" classes which is "Need this text"

for this i did following code.

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".accordprefix").each(function(){
alert($(this).next().html());
});
});
```

but its not working.Please give any suggestions.

Comment: Because it is not wrapped in a specific object it is within parent element of the `.accordprefix` span. You could do `$(".accordprefix").each(function(){$(this).parent().html();});` but then you would need to filter out all the other HTML you do not need.

Comment: You have more than one accordprefix and accordsuffix elements ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873650/jquery-nextuntil-include-text-nodes

Answer (score 6):

You can also look at

```
$.trim($($('.accordprefix')[0].nextSibling).text())
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VX4HF/)

Answer (score 5):

how about:

```
console.log( $('.technology3').text() );
```

since it's the only text content in the surrounding `div`, that would work.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.technology3).text().trim();
```

You want to call `trim()` on it to clear out the garbage white space that surrounds it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if `div.technology3` are multiple,

```
$(".accordprefix").each(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('.technology3').text());// get the closest div.technology3 text
});
```

Read [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text)

if `div.technology3` are single then try this,

```
alert($('.technology3').text());
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LVHh2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.technology3').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add 2 markers (just a small string like '~~~~'). First AFTER `span.accordprefix`, second BEFORE `span.accordsuffix`. Then we need to get text content of `div.technology3`, find text between our markers and store it. Then we need to remove markers.

Check `.after() and .before()`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jQuery [.nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
$("#id_of_first_ele").nextUntil("#id_of_second_ele").text().trim()
```

So in your case it will be

```
$(".accordprefix").nextUntil(".accordsuffix").text().trim()
```

This will work jQuery 1.4 onwards.