# Read all text between non-sibling HTML tags

Tags: jquery, tags, between

I have an HTML page (created from drupal) that, near the top of the page at a place of my choosing, has

```
<span class="marker-start"></span>
```

and near the end, at a place of my choosing, has

```
<span class="marker-end"></span>
```

In between those is some HTML written by users that will probably but not definitely be well formed.

The user can add additional tags like the above, so as to exclude content, eg:

```
<span class="marker-end"></span>
<div>This HTML here is excluded</div>
<span class="marker-start"></span>
```

Note that the exclusion block begins with a 'marker-end', as that matches the 'marker-start' at the beginning of the page to form a pair, and similarly the exclusion block ends with a 'marker-start' to pair with the 'marker-end' at the end of the document (or the start of another exclusion block).

While theoretically that exclusion block will be well formed, I will say again: written by users. Tags may legitimately be opened or closed in an uneven way (for example, the /div may be AFTER the marker-start), and so on. Basically, there is no guarantee that the markers will be siblings.

The user can add multiple excluded spans within the document.

I need a way to read the text (NOT the HTML) between each pair of 'marker-start' and 'marker-end', and that text (which will exclude any exclusion blocks) will be concatenated together. The markers may not (in fact almost certainly will not) be siblings in a balanced position, ie there will probably be tags that are opened but not closed, or vice versa, between them.

I have tried the methods suggested in [How to select all content between two tags in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481076/how-to-select-all-content-between-two-tags-in-jquery) and [Get text between two elements JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767677/get-text-between-two-elements-jquery) and hit problems on all of them.

In general, I have really struggled to have jQuery produce any useful results.

Can anyone suggest the simplest method to achieve this? I do have two solutions which I will outline in an answer for others to see but neither is perfect.

Comment: *"...and hit problems on all of them."* **What** problems? They seem directly applicable.

Comment: Also take a look a the jQuery `contents()` method, which returns all DOM nodes in the selection (including text nodes normally excluded by jQuery filters). No jQuery solution will necessarily work on badly formed HTML though. A Regex against on the HTML would be the fallback to identify such blocks of text and remove them. Ideally you need to do this server-side, before the browser renders it (or in an Ajax load).

Comment: Well, @T. J. Crowder, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481076/how-to-select-all-content-between-two-tags-in-jquery I found that all of the answers only related to cases where the two bounding tags were siblings, or one was a parent of the other, which is not the case in my question. The between function offered didn't seem to work right, IIRC it was because index() is for matching sibling tags.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767677/get-text-between-two-elements-jquery many of the questions relied on the setup of the question, using 'div.technology3'; the only other answer seemed not to fit my case either though perhaps if I had played with it more I could have found otherwise.

I also looked through a bunch of other questions but didn't find one that seemed to match.

Comment: The only solution I could not rule out was from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481076/how-to-select-all-content-between-two-tags-in-jquery , the $("#secondSelector").prevAll('#firstSelector ~ *") - once I made the "s a ' it worked but returned an object that I had no idea how to use, all jQuery functions I tried (eg .css, .text, .html, etc) gave errors or empty results, so that I could not even check if it was a useful result or not.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I'll check out contents(). Perhaps if I used a global variable to store whether or not I am in a marked block... Also, I should point out that the HTML **as a page** should be well formed, or reasonably so. It's from Drupal, and CKEditor should tidy the content up. However the placement of the <span>s that act as markers can be anywhere in the page contents, and so when extracting what is between them there is no guarantee that THAT will be well formed, as there will almost certainly be tags being opened and not closed (as the closing tag is after the marker), or vice versa.

Comment: If you can guarantee the markers are at the same level in the DOM, `contents()` should allow you to rip out text, but my gut feel is to use a non-greedy Regex to replace the marked blocks in the raw HTML. Can these blocks be nested?

Comment: Scratch that second idea. If the marker tags are jagged, a Regex solution could remove closing unmatched tags of other elements.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, yeah, they are not guaranteed to be at the same level. As for nested blocks, I could specify either way if it helped - yes, I have to make it as easy as possible for the users but there are limits, if it is necessary then it can be so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59496/discussion-between-james-carlyle-clarke-and-trueblueaussie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try walking the entire DOM, recursively, and exclude elements based on prior start and end markers found:

As a simple example (if I understand your exclusion logic correctly):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fdductdg/2/

```
function walkDOM(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkDOM(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
};

var inMarker = false;

walkDOM(document.body, function (node) {
    var $node = $(node);
    if ($node.is('span')) {
        if ($node.hasClass('marker-end')) {
            inMarker = false;
            console.log("end marker");
        } else if ($node.hasClass("marker-start")) {
            inMarker = true;
            console.log("start marker");
        }
    }
    if (node.nodeType == 3)
    {
        if (!inMarker)
        {
            // Not inside a marker, remove the text content
            node.textContent = "";
        }
    }
});
```

**Update:**

As you also wish to retain the original text, you can either collect it in a variable (as you appear to have done in comment) or wrap any matching text nodes in appropriate elements (e.g. a span with appropriate class) so that the excluded text can simply be styled-in/out, without destroying the content.

Comment: well, that was fascinating. I learned two properties of a node I did not know existed, and a handy javascript trick (passing the function as a way to separate out the recursion from the action - normally I just call the function explicitly). Nice! Thanks.

Comment: The only problem is this solution changes the page (permanently unless we made the effort to revert it), and although I don't explicitly say it in the original question, I need the original page intact (hence 'I need a way to read the text'). That's why in my suggested solution I undo changes to the page. Still, this was anything but a waste of time, it was a pleasure to see your code, thanks!

Comment: If you can explain the actual result you want (temp hiding of the text etc?) I may be able to offer an improvement to this. All this one does, so far, is identify the text nodes and "do something" with them. An obvious solution would be to wrap any matching text nodes in spans+class that can be styled-in/out, without destroying the content.

Comment: So what I did was, under the line `var inMarker = false;` I added a line `var aggregate = "";`. Then in the if block of `if (node.nodeType == 3)` I changed it to `if (inMarker) { /* Inside a marker, so add the text content to the aggregate */ aggregate = aggregate + node.textContent; }` (but with better formatting, this has to work within the comment!). Now it does what I want, placing the result in `aggregate`. Thanks again, @TrueBlueAussie! If you would care to edit your answer, or add a new one, then I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

One really bad option would be to get the HTML as a string, and then go through using string analysis, find the markers, grab the HTML between them, and then use some kind of HTML parser to reduce that to text. Yuck!

A better solution I found was:

1) I added unique ids to the page's outermost opening and closing markers (the ones I control), eg

```
<span class="marker-start" id="primary-marker-start"></span>
...
<span class="marker-end" id="primary-marker-end"></span>
```

2) I used the following to get the text:

```
var start_class = 'marker-start';
var end_class = 'marker-end';
var start_tag = '<start>';
var end_tag = '<end>';
var absolute_start_id = "#primary-marker-start";
var absolute_end_id = "#primary-marker-end";

// put convenient markers into the actual text that will be returned,
// to enable simple parsing - note that this will dump anything already there
// so for example, <span class="marker-start"></span>
// becomes <span class="marker-start">&lt;start&gt;</span>
jQuery("." + start_class).text(start_tag);
jQuery("." + end_class).text(end_tag);

// get the text between the two outermost markers -
// including the convenient markers added above
var content = start_tag + jQuery(absolute_start_id).nextAll().not(absolute_end_id).text();

// remove the convenient markers so they don't show up on the page
jQuery("." + start_class).text("");
jQuery("." + end_class).text("");

// at this point, content holds all the text
// between and including absolute_start_id and absolute_end_id,
// with start_tag in place of the start markers, (eg '<start>')
// and end_tag in place of the end markers
// (including at the beginning and end of the text)
```

After this it is a relatively trivial act to process that string and remove anything between end and start markers appropriately, and so on.

Can anyone suggest a better idea or ways to improve on this? I am not a jQuery expert so would welcome tips or solutions.