# jQuery nextUntil include text nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I'm using `nextUntil` method to get all stuff between two elements. But this method does not include `text nodes` to output. It gives an array like `[<br>, <br>, <br>]`. How can I get all stuff including text nodes?

This is the HTML code:

```js
$('.content a:contains("spoiler").b:even').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('.content a:contains("spoiler").b')
    .wrapAll('<div style="border:solid 1px black;"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  --- <a class="b" href="/?q=spoiler">spoiler</a> ---
  <br>
  <br> dangerous text here
  <br> --- <a class="b" href="/?q=spoiler">spoiler</a> ---
  <br> safe text here
  <br> --- <a class="b" href="/?q=spoiler">spoiler</a> ---
  <br>
  <br> dangerous text here
  <br> --- <a class="b" href="/?q=spoiler">spoiler</a> ---
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwk97rvq/1/

Comment: Only `.contents()` returns text nodes.

Comment: how can i modify code for `contents()` ?

Comment: Potential answer below (If I understand the aim correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the jQuery `.contents()` method returns all nodes (including text nodes, normally ignored).

So maybe something like this?:

http://jsfiddle.net/ykv3gf5L/2/

```
$('.content').each(function () {
    var open = false;
    var result = $();
    $(this).contents().each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text() == "spoiler") {
            if (open) {
                result.wrapAll('<div style="border:solid 1px black;"></div>');
                open = false;
            } else {
                result = $();
                open = true;
            }
        } else {
            result = result.add($this)
        }
    });
    if (open) {
        result.wrapAll('<div style="border:solid 1px black;"></div>');
    }
});
```

It just iterate all nodes and based on a flag starts a new collection, or wraps the nodes found.

The final `if (open)` allows for an unclosed spolier block within a `content` classed div.

Notes:

- `$()` is an empty jQuery collection (like an empty array but for jQuery objects)
- I suggest you use a style for your spoilers and use a class e.g. `result.wrapAll('<div class="spoiler"></div>');`

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ykv3gf5L/3/

Answer (score 8):

You can create your own jquery plugin which does the same as `nextUntil` but includes text nodes:

```
$.fn.nextUntilWithTextNodes = function (until) {
    var matched = $.map(this, function (elem, i, until) {
        var matched = [];
        while ((elem = elem.nextSibling) && elem.nodeType !== 9) {
            if (elem.nodeType === 1 || elem.nodeType === 3) {
                if (until && jQuery(elem).is(until)) {
                    break;
                }
                matched.push(elem);
            }
        }
        return matched;
    }, until);

    return this.pushStack(matched);
};
```

So you can call this `nextUntilWithTextNodes` instead of `nextUntil` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks! You just made my day.

Comment: Oh my ! .. I wish I could upvote this a 100 times ! :)

Comment: Is `pushStack()` at the end needed; if so, why?