# How to hide content between two specific id by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to hide everything between two certain divs with different ids.

For example:

```
<div id="a1">Hi</div>
<div>Some Random Text</div>
<div id="a2">Hello</div>
```

Like in above example, I want to hide the div between id a1 and a2.

Comment: if you hide directly than used to css #a1, #a2{display:none;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [nextAll](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) with [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

```js
$('#a1').hide().nextAll().each(function() {
  $(this).hide();

  if ($(this).attr('id') === 'a2') {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>HELLO</div>
<div id="a1">Hi</div>
<div>Some Random Text</div>
<div id="a2">Hello</div>
<div>BYE</div>
```

Comment: Could you edit it to be more portable? Like when ID changes?

Comment: Please leave a comment when downvote to improve the answer.

Comment: @TomášZato You just need to change selector appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using [nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/). In one line:

```
$("#a1").nextUntil("#a2").hide();
```

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    var hideElement = $("#a1").nextUntil("#a2");
    hideElement.hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="a1">Hi</div>
<div>Some Random Text</div>
<div>Some Random Text</div>
<div id="a2">Hello</div>
<button id="hide">hide</button>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41dxnjLt/)

Note that `nextUntil()` doesn't include stray text nodes, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873650/jquery-nextuntil-include-text-nodes) for a solution to that.

Answer (score 2):

HI now you can hide this in `css`

```css
    #a1, #a1 ~ #a2{display:none;}
```

```html
<div id="a1">Hi</div>
    <div>Some Random Text</div>
    <div id="a2">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cotrols are all siblings, you can use the `.nextUntil()` or `.prevUntil()` jQuery selector. See [this](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) or [this](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) for details.
If however the controls don't share the same parent, there's no simple selector. You'll have to create a method to find the parents of the controls and propably their parents etc.

Answer (score 0):

use simple jquery,

```
$("#a1+div").hide();
```

or using css

```
#a1+div{
display: none;
}
```

if you want to delete everything between those two divs try this,

```
$("#a1").nextAll().each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id") != "a2"){
        $(this).hide();
    }
    else{
        //element found with id 'a2' so exit;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you hide by  using the css only.

```css
#a1,#a2 {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="a1">Hi</div>
    <div>Some Random Text</div>
    <div id="a2">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

ITs simply use the element id  and hide() function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$("#a1,#a2").hide();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1">Hi</div>
<div>Some Random Text</div>
<div id="a2">Hello</div>
```

.