# Wrap a javascript generated html structure in a span with multiple instances of the end point

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, syntax-highlighting, velocity

I've been working on a syntax highlighter for a slightly modified version of [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/). In short how can I wrap all the content starting at `#inline()` and ending with the corresponding `#end` under the condition that there can be 0-infinite if statements that will always have an `#end`. Let me know if you have any questions.

Example can be found on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxplosions/4q1uLogu/). See the below for more detailed information.

**Sample HTML**

The fiddle shows the post javascript modified version of the below html.

```
<pre><code>
$javascript.push("/path/to/file")
#inline()
    $('.lazy.bg2').attr({'data-src':'/img_path2.jpg'}).css('background','red');
    #if($myVar == "hi")
       $('.someClass).hide()
    #elseif($myVar == "there")
       $('.lazy.bg1').attr({'data-src':'/img_path.jpg'})
    #else
       $('.lazy.bg3').attr({'data-src':'/img_path3.jpg'})
    #end
    $('.lazy.bg2 a').attr({'data-href':'/random-path2.htm'})
    $('.lazy.bg1 a').attr({'data-href':'/random-path.htm'})
#end

#if($test.method == "myVal")
  #set($foo = "swag")
#elseif($foo == "bar")
  #set($foo = "ballin")
#elseif($myObject.randomMethod().contains("myVal"))
  #set($foo = "weeee")
#else
  #set($foo = "sad days")
#end
#set($testVar = "Test value")
#parse("/path/to/file")</code></pre>
```

**The Problem**

Since there are multiple instances of `#end` I'm not sure how to get it to match the end to the `#inline()` statement. The main problem being is that there could be an infinite number of if statements, but the `#inline()` will always have a corresponding end statement. So I'm guessing the best approach would be to match it based on it being the same white-space level. However I'm not sure if there is a better solution. I found the original javascript in [Gone Coding's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201078/gone-coding) post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25873943). However I've slightly modified it to better match my implementation. *Note I'm adding the velocity class to the `<pre>` in an earlier jQuery statement.* The end result should only apply the `<span>` to the jQuery inside the `#inline()`.

**Javascript**

```
$('pre.velocity code').each(function () {
    var open = false;
    var result = $();
    $(this).contents().each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text() == "#inline()" || $this.text() == "#end") {
            if (open) {
                result.wrapAll('<span class="velocity-inline-inner"></span>');
                open = false;
            } else {
                result = $();
                open = true;
            }
        } else {
            result = result.add($this)
        }
    });
    if (open) {
        result.wrapAll('<span class="velocity-inline-inner"></span>');
    }
});
```

***Updated Javascript***

I have the following that can count the white space and selects the `#end` that matches white space level of the `#inline()`, however I am having the issue of converting just that substring to html within the if statement.

```
$('pre.velocity code').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).text();
  str = str.substring(str.indexOf("#inline()") + 10);
  textArray = str.split("\n");
  getInlineEnd(str,textArray);
});

function getInlineEnd(str,textArray) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= textArray.length; i++) {
      if(textArray[i].length === 4 && textArray[i] === "#end") {
        //convert textArray[i] to a html node and then wrap with a <span>
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

**End Goal HTML**

The end result should look something like the below. I'm adding a span around the `#inline()` and `#end` already.

```
#inline()
<span class="velocity-inline-inner">
    $('.lazy.bg2').attr({'data-src':'/img_path2.jpg'}).css('background','red');
    #if($myVar == "hi")
       $('.someClass).hide()
    #elseif($myVar == "there")
       $('.lazy.bg1').attr({'data-src':'/img_path.jpg'})
    #else
       $('.lazy.bg3').attr({'data-src':'/img_path3.jpg'})
    #end
    $('.lazy.bg2 a').attr({'data-href':'/random-path2.htm'})
    $('.lazy.bg1 a').attr({'data-href':'/random-path.htm'})
</span>
#end
```

I believe once I get the above code working correctly then it should syntax highlight appropriately. The end goal though is to get all of the jQuery method values highlighting. I am going to be handling the selector under a different regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the below js and html to wrap the `#inline()` and the corresponding `#end` based on whitespace. This was the html rendered by the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxplosions/4q1uLogu/).

```js
    // Loop thorugh each of the velocity and see if there is an inline to syntax highlight.
    $('pre.velocity code').each(function(){
        var html = $(this).html();
        var str = html.toString(html); // convert html object to a string
        str = str.substring(str.indexOf("#inline()") + 17); // split the string so only take half of it.
        var textArray = str.split("\n"); // split the array on a new line
        var newHtml = getInlineEnd(textArray);
        regExVelocity($(this),str,newHtml); // replace the string
    });

    /**
     * Loops through the inline and finds the #end based on white-space
     * @param textArray
     * @type Array
     * @returns {string|*}
     */
    function getInlineEnd(textArray) {
        // loop through each line of the string.
        for(var i = 0; i <= textArray.length; i++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                // first line in #inline()
                textArray[i] = "<span class=\"velocity-inline-inner\">"+textArray[i]
            }
            if(undefined !== textArray[i] && textArray[i].length === 38 && textArray[i] === "<span class=\"velocity-end\">#end</span>") {
                // Found the end of the #inline() based on white-space. Update the text.
                textArray[i] = textArray[i].replace(textArray[i],'</span><span class="velocity-end">#end</span>');
                // break out of the for loop since we got the value
                break;
            }
        }
        // return the string and reformat it.
        return textArray.join('\n');
    }

    /**
     * Runs regex for velocity syntax highlighting uses .html() if you want to use the text then use regExText
     * @param selector
     * @param regex
     * @param output
     */
    function regExVelocity(selector, regex, output) {
        selector.html(function(i, html) {
            return( html.replace(regex, output));
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="velocity"><code>
<span class="velocity-object">$javascript</span>.push(<span class="velocity-string">"/path/to/file"</span>)
<span class="velocity-inline">#inline()</span>
    $('.lazy.bg2').attr({'data-src':'/img_path2.jpg'}).css('background','red');
    <span class="velocity-if">#if(</span><span class="velocity-if-inner">$myVar == "hi"</span><span class="velocity-if">)</span>
    #elseif($myVar == "there")
          $('.lazy.bg1').attr({'data-src':'/img_path.jpg'})
    #else
          $('.lazy.bg3').attr({'data-src':'/img_path3.jpg'})
    <span class="velocity-end">#end</span>
    $('.lazy.bg1 a').attr({'data-href':'/random-path.htm'})
<span class="velocity-end">#end</span>
<span class="velocity-if">#if(</span><span class="velocity-if-inner"><span class="velocity-object">$test</span>.method == "myVal"</span><span class="velocity-if">)</span>
  <span class="velocity-set">#set(</span><span class="velocity-inner"><span class="velocity-variable">$foo </span><span class="equalSign">=</span> "swag"</span><span class="velocity-set">)</span>
#elseif($foo == "bar")
  <span class="velocity-set">#set(</span><span class="velocity-inner"><span class="velocity-variable">$foo </span><span class="equalSign">=</span> "ballin"</span><span class="velocity-set">)</span>
#elseif(<span class="velocity-object">$myObject</span>.randomMethod().contains(<span class="velocity-string">"myVal"</span>))
  <span class="velocity-set">#set(</span><span class="velocity-inner"><span class="velocity-variable">$foo </span><span class="equalSign">=</span> "weeee"</span><span class="velocity-set">)</span>
#else
  <span class="velocity-set">#set(</span><span class="velocity-inner"><span class="velocity-variable">$foo </span><span class="equalSign">=</span> "sad days"</span><span class="velocity-set">)</span>
<span class="velocity-end">#end</span>
<span class="velocity-set">#set(</span><span class="velocity-inner"><span class="velocity-variable">$testVar </span><span class="equalSign">=</span> "Test value"</span><span class="velocity-set">)</span>
<span class="velocity-parse">#parse(</span><span class="velocity-parse-path">"/path/to/file"</span><span class="velocity-parse">)</span></code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at your code, but it's a bit of a beast. So I'll give a more general overview. First you need to be able to parse (to some small degree) some of the parts of your input (for this, #inline, #if, and #end). Then you need to count the number of openings that would close with #end. Then as each #end comes along, you check the latest opening off the list. When you get to the #end that would close the opening #inline, that's where you close off that `</span>`.

**Note: I haven't tested the code. I don't know exactly how the code originally worked and so on. I'm just using it as pseudo-code to show what kind of things you'll need to do.**

```
$('pre.velocity code').each(function () {
    var open = [];
    var result = $();
    $(this).contents().each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text() == "#inline()" || $this.text().substr("#if(") === 0) {
            open.push($this);
        }
        else if ($this.text() == "#end") {
            var toClose = open.pop();
            if (toClose.text() === "#inline()") {
                // wrap from after #inline() to before #end
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ends up saying that there is a TypeError where it can't read text property of undefined and points to `if (toClose.text() === "#inline()") {`. So it sounds like the pop() isn't returning an object with a text node.

Comment: Oh right. Best do some debugging then? As I say, I don't fully understand your code, so the code probably won't work just copy/pasted.