# How to wrap previous and next sibling text of <br> with div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nextsibling

Following HTML structure is given and cannot be changed:

```html
<div id="cone" class="team">
  <div class="default"></div>
  ...
  <div class="default">
    <img src="img.jpg" width="271" height="271" alt="" border="0"> First Text line<br> Second text line (optional)
    <img src="img.jpg" width="271" height="271" alt="" border="0"> First Text line<br> Second text line (optional) ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get to the following result using jQuery:

```html
<div id="cone" class="team">
  <div class="default"></div>
  ...
  <div class="default">
    <img src="img.jpg" width="271" height="271" alt="" border="0">
    <div class="desc">
      First Text line<br> Second text line (optional)
    </div>
    <img src="img.jpg" width="271" height="271" alt="" border="0">
    <div class="desc">
      First Text line<br> Second text line (optional)
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
$(".team img").each(function () {
    $(this.nextSibling).wrap('<div class="desc"></div>');
});
```

But this only wraps the first line:

```
<img src="fileadmin/dateien/bilder/team/platzhalter_team.jpg" width="271" height="271" alt="" border="0">
<div class="desc">First Text line</div>
<br>
Second text line (optional)
```

Important: There can be one line, two lines, even three lines of text after the `<img>` Tag.

Comment: I tried nextUntil, but that wraps `br` tag only: `$(this.nextSibling).nextUntil('img').wrapAll('<div></div>');`

Comment: .content http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873650/jquery-nextuntil-include-text-nodes

Comment: @mplungjan: Sorry, can't get it to work with that code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate `br` element in `.default` and add your new tag in loop. You can get previous/next text sibling of element using [`Node.previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) and [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property.

```
$(".default > br").each(function(){
    // Store previous/next sibling of br in variable then remove it.
    var prev = $(this.previousSibling).remove()[0].textContent;
    var next = $(this.nextSibling).remove()[0].textContent;
    // Insert new tag before br.
    $(this).before("<div class='desc'>" + prev + "<br>" + next + "</div>");  
}).remove(); // Remove br after loop
```

```js
$(".default > br").each(function(){
    var prev = $(this.previousSibling).remove()[0].textContent;
    var next = $(this.nextSibling).remove()[0].textContent;
    $(this).before("<div class='desc'>" + prev + "<br>" + next + "</div>");
}).remove();
```

```css
.desc { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cone" class="team">    
    <div class="default"></div> 
    <div class="default">       
        <img src="img.jpg" width="271" height="271" alt="" border="0">
        First Text line<br>
        Second text line (optional)
        <img src="img.jpg" width="271" height="271" alt="" border="0">
        First Text line<br>
        Second text line (optional)
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit:**

If your html has multiple `<br>`, you need to replace br with custom text and after wrap, replace target text to `<br>`. In example i used `[br]`.

```
$(".default").html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace(/<br>/g, "[br]");
});
$(".default > img").each(function(){
    $(this.nextSibling).wrap('<div class="desc"></div>');
});
$(".default").html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace(/\[br\]/g, "<br>");
});
```

```js
$(".default").html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace(/<br>/g, "[br]");
});
$(".default > img").each(function(){
    $(this.nextSibling).wrap('<div class="desc"></div>');
});
$(".default").html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace(/\[br\]/g, "<br>");
});
```

```css
.desc { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cone" class="team">    
    <div class="default"></div> 
    <div class="default">       
        <img src="img.jpg" width="271" height="271" alt="" border="0">
        First Text line<br>
        Second text line (optional)<br>
        Third text line
        <img src="img.jpg" width="271" height="271" alt="" border="0">
        First Text line<br>
        Second text line (optional)<br>
        Third text line
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, great, thanks! It works perfectly for 2 lines separated with `<br>` but as mentioned in the initial question: There can also be 1 line (without `<br>` of course) and 3 lines. And then this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can ad id to "br", and wrapAll by id list

```
<div id="id1">First</div><br id="id2">
<div id="id2">Second</div><br>
<div id="id3">First</div><br id="id4">

<script>
$("#id1,#id2,#id3,#id4").wrapAll("<div class='wraped'></div>")
</script>
```