# How to wrap string which is sibling to strong tag in new tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nextsibling

In an html like the sample below, I need to wrap the `text I need to select` part in a span tag with a custom class, but how do I select just that part excluding the content in the `strong` tags above it, using jquery?

```
<span>
  <strong> random gibberish </strong>
  text I need to select
</span>
```

Edit: simply using `.text()` on parent won't work because that converts the whole inner html to text including the part in `strong`

Comment: what's your actual requirement

Comment: Have you tried $(strong).parent().text();

Comment: @melvin The actual requirement is to highlight the product names in a html list which I am being sent from an api call. I do not have access to the api code itself.

Comment: @Mowzey yes, that gives `random gibberish text I need to select` , basically converts the entire inner html to text.

Comment: $("span").clone().children().remove().end().text();

Comment: @benvc ✌ great looking out

Comment: @benvc thanks, but how do I put the modified text back in that span replacing that original text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wrap previous and next sibling text of <br> with div using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685334/how-to-wrap-previous-and-next-sibling-text-of-br-with-div-using-jquery)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) and eq functions:

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  $(this).contents().eq(2).wrap('<span class="someClass"/>')
});
```

```css
.someClass {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <strong> random gibberish </strong>
  text I need to select
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nextSibling.nodeValue to get the text immediately after the strong tag. Then you can do a replace() on the text content to wrap the tags around it - I am doing it using a span with a newClass and related styling.

```js
var strongEl = document.querySelector('strong');
var siblingEl = strongEl.nextSibling.nodeValue;
var spanContent = $('span').html();
var newSpanContent = '<span class="newClass">'+siblingEl +'</span>';
$('span').html(spanContent.replace(siblingEl, newSpanContent));

console.log(siblingEl);
```

```css
span.newClass {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <strong> random gibberish </strong>
  text I need to select
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.after( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to do this work. So in function callback get next text of `strong` using `nextSibling` property and wrap it in `span`

```js
$("span > strong").after(function(){
  return "<span class='new'>"+$(this.nextSibling).remove().text()+"</div>";  
});
```

```css
.new {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <strong> random gibberish </strong>
  text I need to select
</span>
```