# jquery: Select <h1> and everything up to the next <h1>

Tags: jquery, html

Imagine this html:

```
<h1>Heading Number one</h1>

foo bar is bla bar....

<table>...</table>

<h1>Heading Number two</h1>

other bar is strange bar ...

...
```

I want to show the parts one after the other.

This means I need to select the `<h1>...</h1>` until the next `<h1>`.

In above example I want to get a list of html snippets:

First list item:

```
<h1>Heading Number one</h1>

foo bar is bla bar....

<table>...</table>
```

Second list item:

```
<h1>Heading Number two</h1>

other bar is strange bar ...

...
```

How to select `<h1>` and everything up to the next `<h1>`?

Just using nextUntil() does not help, since the text is not in a tag.

Maybe putting all text in a tag, and then call nextUntil() or a different solution....

Comment: use nextUntil in jquery  ref https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_nextuntil.asp

Comment: If you need the text nodes, see [jQuery nextUntil include text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25873650/215552)

Comment: You can easily select use jquery `your element.nextAll()` function, but problem is your also contant some solid text. jquery normally not select solid text it's needed for follwing steps:

1. get all html form **h1** instant parent 
2. find the **h1** string start index and endindex
3. after endindex after html keeps in a `temp valiable`
4. and remove ther next string after endindex
5. create a new element and append `temp variable`
6. then you style the normally like as normal element style use jquery.

Answer (score 1):

use `nextUntil` in jquery ref https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/ for more details,hope this helps

```js
$("h1").eq(0).nextUntil("h1").css('color','red')  //Selecting first h1 element
$("h1").eq(1).nextUntil("h1").css('color','green')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Heading Number one</h1>

<p>foo  </p>

<p>foo  </p>

<p>foo </p>

<h1>Heading Number two</h1>
<p>  bar  </p>

<p>  bar </p>

<p>  bar </p>

<h1>Heading Number three</h1>
```

Comment: The OP doesn't put text in `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for [nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
$("h1:first-of-type").nextUntil("h1")
```

Comment: The `.nextUntil()` only select elements. The text **foo bar is bla bar....** doesn't selected