# Wrapping elements between two elements inside a div

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to turn

```
<h2>Headline 1</h2>

<p>Any</p>
<ul>
  <li>HTML</li>
</ul>
<span>elements</span>

<h2>Headline 2</h2>

<h3>Some other</h3>
<p>HTML elements</p>
```

into

```
<h2>Headline 1</h2>
<div>
    <p>Any</p>
    <ul>
      <li>HTML</li>
    </ul>
    <span>elements</span>
</div>
 
<h2>Headline 2</h2>
<div>
  <h3>Some other</h3>
  <p>HTML elements</p>
</div>
```

The number of h2 is unpredictable. All code i found only works with siblings or I didnt get it to work (insertAfter, insert, wrapAll, etc.)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use `.nextUntil()` to get all the elements up to the next `<h2>`. Then use `.wrapAll()` to put them inside a `<div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the absence of text nodes is guaranteed, then `.nextUntil()` can be used as @Barmar suggested.
Otherwise, an additional effort like [using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25873943) `.contents()` is required to make sure all sibling nodes are included.

```js
$('h2').each((i, h) => {
  const group = [];
  let started = false;
  $(h).parent().contents().each((j, sib) => {
    const proceed = !started || !$(sib).is('h2');
    if (started && proceed) {
      group.push(sib);
    }
    started = (h == sib) || started;
    return proceed;
  });
  $(group).wrapAll('<div>');
});
```

```css
div {
  background: #bfb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h2>Headline 1</h2>

<p>Any</p>
<ul>
  <li>HTML</li>
</ul>
<span>elements</span>

<h2>Headline 2</h2>

<h3>Some other</h3>
text node and
<p>HTML elements</p>
```